# タグシノニムの提案: makefile ← make

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

[make](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) と [makefile](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) が両方存在することに気付きました。

[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/makefile/info)に合わせて [makefile](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) をマスターとしてタグシノニムにし、更にタグのマージをしたいです。いかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

賛成票が多く反対意見が無かったため、タグのマージとタグシノニムの作成を行いました ✅

マージログ：

```
updating post history, 19 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 17 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 12 rows affected
destroying 'make': [make] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 24
tag remapping of [makefile] and [make] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```